# ¿Cómo se puede hacer una condicional con una variable que no tiene algún dato?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una variable llamada "rela" la cual trae datos de una consulta si hay una coincidencia con la tabla de la base de datos(esto ya lo he probado y funciona). Esto lo hago en un `fetch()` o promesa, ahora quiero cambiar el código que tengo ya que tengo pensado en una condicional consultar si la variable es `NULL`.

Esto es lo que tengo

```
fetch('prdSimilares.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
         })
         .then(res =>  res.json())
         .then(dataS => {
            let rela = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataS));
            let html = ' ';      
            for (let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++) {            
               html += `<div class="item">
                           <img class="img-trj-prodRela" src="${rela[i].foto}" alt="${rela[i].nombre}" id="${rela[i].categoria},${rela[i].subcategoria},${rela[i].nombre},${rela[i].codigo},${rela[i].id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">                                                      
                        </div>`;
            }
            ...
            ...
         });
```

lo que he intentado:
primeramente comenté lo del bucle for e hice un `console.log(typeof rela)` obtengo que rela es un objeto, luego realicé`console.log(rela)` para ver que se obtenía y la respuesta fue un `[null]`; ya con esto intenté poner un

```
if (rela === null){
   console.log('vacio');
   //ocultar contenedor
} else {
   for (let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++) { 
   ...
   ...
   }
}
```

Pero no se me mostró en consola el mensaje de "vacio" e hizo el código del bucle for, también intente usando el operador `==` y de igual forma no se mostro el mensaje y se realizo el bucle.

No le quiero dejar sin esta condicional ya que en consola quedaría el error de esta parte. **¿ De qué manera puedo consultar si la variable es nula?**

Comment: Por lo que indicas rela es un array que trae [null] para validar deberías colocar en el if(rela[0] === null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como previamente había hecho la consulta relacionada al tipo de dato (`typeof`) y como me decía también en consola que tenía un `length` de 1 intuí que es un arreglo a pesar de que no fue declarada como tal, por lo tanto la condicional que realice es:
``
if (rela[rela.length - 1] == null) {
console.log("vacio");
...
} else {
for(let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++){
html += .....;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

La comprobación que haces la debes hacer dentro del loop en éste caso. Lo que pasa es que la variable rela no es null porque es un Array.

```
let rela = dataS;
let html = ' ';

for (let i = 0; i < rela.length; i++) {
 if (rela[i] === null) {//AQUI ES DONDE NECESITAS COMPROBAR
    console.log('vacio');
 } else {
    html += `<div class="item">
                       <img class="img-trj-prodRela" src="${rela[i].foto}" alt="${rela[i].nombre}" id="${rela[i].categoria},${rela[i].subcategoria},${rela[i].nombre},${rela[i].codigo},${rela[i].id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">
                       <div class="nombre_producto">
                          <h2 id="${rela[i].categoria},${rela[i].subcategoria},${rela[i].nombre},${rela[i].codigo},${rela[i].id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">${rela[i].nombre}</h2>
                       </div>                           
                    </div>`;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yo pienso que debería comprobarla antes de hacer lo del bucle, pero gracias @Wisquimas por tu respuesta ya la voy a poner a prueba

Comment: Yo antes del loop haría otro tipo de comprobaciones como por ejemplo if(Array.isArray(rela)). Además ten en cuenta que tu linea donde defines rela es excesiva. En realidad rela es igual a dataS. Pero prueba y me dices

Answer (score 0):

No se, ya que no se lo que llega del fetch, estaría bien ver un ejemplo de la respuesta.

De todas maneras puedes hacer esto, si la variable es null nunca entraría dentro del bucle:

```
rela?.forEach(x => {
        html += `<div class="item">
                       <img class="img-trj-prodRela" src="${x.foto}" alt="${x.nombre}" id="${x.categoria},${x.subcategoria},${x.nombre},${x.codigo},${x.id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">
                       <div class="nombre_producto">
                          <h2 id="${x.categoria},${x.subcategoria},${x.nombre},${x.codigo},${x.id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">${x.nombre}</h2>
                       </div>                           
                    </div>`;
        }
        document.getElementById('relacionados').innerHTML = html;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, te recomiendo una optimización, porque no tiene caso interpretar la respuesta del servidor como JSON con `res => res.json()` para después convertir en cadena y volver a interpretar con `let rela = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataS));`, solo estás complicando la lógica y dando más trabajo del necesario al navegador.

De acuerdo a la respuesta que obtienes en la consola `[null]`, se trata de un arreglo con un solo elemento nulo.

```
fetch('prdSimilares.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
})
// Aquí ya estás interpretando la respuesta como JSON
.then(res =>  res.json())
// Usa directamente la variable como parámetro de la función flecha
.then(rela => {
    let html = ' ';
    // Si solo hay un elemento y es nulo, evitar entrar al ciclo
    if(rela.length == 1 && rela[0] === null) {
        // No entras al ciclo
    } else {
        // En lugar de un for, puedes simplificar con forEach
        rela.forEach(item => {
            html += `<div class="item">
                   <img class="img-trj-prodRela" src="${item.foto}" alt="${item.nombre}" id="${item.categoria},${item.subcategoria},${item.nombre},${item.codigo},${item.id_cat}" onclick="javascript: clave()">                                                      
                </div>`;
        });
});
```

Otros dos problemas que veo:

1. Estás creando el atributo ID muy largo, probablemente iniciando con número y con caracteres inválidos; te sugiero usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) para tener mejor control de los elementos
2. En el evento `onclick` sobra el protocolo `javascript:`, ya no es necesario y, además, al ejecutar la función no estás enviando un parámetro que permita identificar dónde se originó el evento

Para el segundo punto, podrías dejar `onclick="clave(event)"` para poder identificar el elemento mediante `event.target`; de cualquier forma, siempre es mejor [element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), aunque es un poco más complicado asignarlo, porque estás creando código HTML en lugar de elementos.

Comment: Sí, tengo que actualizar el código también, gracias por tu comentario